# Bitwise Operator Execution in Perl

Tags: perl, logical-operators

I am having an issue with understanding the execution of the following code:

```
my $input = 1;
print ("Statement") if ($input != 1 || $input != 2);
```

versus:

```
my $input = 1; 
print ("Statement") if ($input != 1 && $input != 2);
```

"Statement" prints with the 'OR' operator unexpectedly.  "Statement" does not print when I use the 'AND' operator which is the result I expected with 'OR'.  "if" $input is not equal to 1 'OR' 2 then print "Statement".

What am I missing?

Comment: 1. You're not using bitwise or/and, but logical or/and. 2. the correct way to parse your first condition is "if ($input is not equal to 1) OR ($input is not equal to 2)" rather than "if $intput is not equal to (1 OR 2)". Since $input has a single value, it's always either "not equal to 1" or "not equal to 2" (or both). Thus, the 1st condition is always true.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!  In essence, I was using poorly worded human language as I understood it.  Good stuff.  Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Is correct.

```
$input = 1
```

So in the Or operator `$input != 1` (false) and `$input != 2` (true).

As at least one of the conditions has been met "Statement" is printed.

Logical Or: Returns True when either the A-operand or the B-operand is True; otherwise, it returns False.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input0 = 1;
print ("Statement0\n") if ($input0 != 1 || $input0 != 2);
print "\n";

my $input1 = 1;
print ("Statement1\n") if ($input1 != 1 && $input1 != 2);
```